# Can Phone Number and Email verfication both be applied in Firebase?

Tags: android, firebase, android-studio, firebase-authentication

I want to make an app which takes in both the email id and contact number of an user(besides some other fields) using Firebase. After that I want to verify both the email id and the contact number of the user by sending an OTP to the user's contact number and a verification email to the user's email id. Can it be done in Firebase? If so then please guide me how. I am using Android Studio.

Comment: Yes. The docs provide a good guide how to achieve this; https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/account-linking?authuser=0

Answer (score 2):

I believe this is possible, although it will be kind of tricky. You will have to implement both [email](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/email-link-auth#completing_sign-in_in_an_android_app) and [phone number](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/phone-auth#verification-callbacks) and on the callbacks add a check to see if both were completed before signing the user in. I think given that email seems to have to sign the user in, you will have to implement phone verification to occur first before email and add a check that the phone was verified before checking email and signing in. Shown in the documentation:

Setup the phone verification as stated in the documentation and for the callbacks

```
mCallbacks = new PhoneAuthProvider.OnVerificationStateChangedCallbacks() {

    @Override
    public void onVerificationCompleted(PhoneAuthCredential credential) {
    // This callback will be invoked in two situations:
    // 1 - Instant verification. In some cases the phone number can be instantly
    //     verified without needing to send or enter a verification code.
    // 2 - Auto-retrieval. On some devices Google Play services can automatically
    //     detect the incoming verification SMS and perform verification without
    //     user action.
    Log.d(TAG, "onVerificationCompleted:" + credential);
    //signInWithPhoneAuthCredential(credential);   //send email for email verification here instead/ sign in with email method
    }
```

Maybe send the email verification once the phone number is confirmed like this

```
//Save the user email address beforehand for this

FirebaseAuth auth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
auth.sendSignInLinkToEmail(email, actionCodeSettings)
        .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "Email sent.");
                }
            }
        });
```

Implement this https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/email-link-auth#completing_sign-in_in_an_android_app to setup dynamic links to complete sign in within the app
and have something like this for the signing in with email method.

```
FirebaseAuth auth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
Intent intent = getIntent();
String emailLink = intent.getData().toString();

// Confirm the link is a sign-in with email link.
if (auth.isSignInWithEmailLink(emailLink)) {
    // Retrieve this from wherever you stored it
    String email = "someemail@domain.com";

    // The client SDK will parse the code from the link for you.
    auth.signInWithEmailLink(email, emailLink)
            .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                    if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                        Log.d(TAG, "Successfully signed in with email link!");
                        AuthResult result = task.getResult();
                        // You can access the new user via result.getUser()
                        // Additional user info profile *not* available via:
                        // result.getAdditionalUserInfo().getProfile() == null
                        // You can check if the user is new or existing:
                        // result.getAdditionalUserInfo().isNewUser()
                    } else {
                        Log.e(TAG, "Error signing in with email link", task.getException());
                    }
                }
            });
}
```

I would think there is a better way to approach this. Maybe some kind of cloud function in the console, but this is the only approach I can find for now.